# Recursive binary search function (in solidity) not working

Tags: solidity, javascript

This is recursive binary search function in solidity. I run the SortTESTER function to populate an array with values. Then I run the SortUserData function to check values which passes the values to FindSpotinArray. It only returns the proper place at 22 or anything above until 439. Why is this? Is the recursive function not working or is the conditional breaking? I can't seem to get it to loop properly. I decided to recreate the memory array in FindSpotinArray function to avoid passing in large memory array of up to 10,000 values, but is the efficient?

```
function SortTESTER(address tokenAddress) public {
        tokenContract[tokenAddress].sortArray = [6, 9, 14, 15, 22, 439, 550, 1111, 1500, 1600];
    }

    function SortUserData(address tokenAddress, uint256 price) public view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 lengthVariable = tokenContract[tokenAddress].sortArray.length;
        uint256[] memory SortAlgo = new uint256[](lengthVariable);
        SortAlgo = tokenContract[tokenAddress].sortArray;
        uint256 x = lengthVariable / 2;
        uint256 tempDivision = x / 2;
        return FindSpotinArray(tempDivision, x, price, tokenAddress);
    }

function FindSpotinArray(
    uint256 tempDivision,
    uint256 x,
    uint256 price,
    address tokenAddress) public view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 lengthVariable = tokenContract[tokenAddress].sortArray.length;
        uint256[] memory SortAlgo = new uint256[](lengthVariable);
        SortAlgo = tokenContract[tokenAddress].sortArray;
        //no point in creating memory structure, just pull directly from the array
        //this is fine, if it's bigger as long as the previous isn't bigger
        if(price < SortAlgo[x] && price < SortAlgo[x - 1] && price != SortAlgo[x]) {
            return FindSpotinArray(tempDivision / 2, x + tempDivision, price, tokenAddress);
        } else if (price > SortAlgo[x] && price > SortAlgo[x - 1] && price != SortAlgo[x]) {
            return FindSpotinArray(tempDivision / 2, x - tempDivision, price, tokenAddress);
        } else if (price == SortAlgo[x]) {
            return x;
        } else if (SortAlgo[x - 1] <= price && price <= SortAlgo[x]) {
            return x;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to implement it as a recursive function? The iterative version will be more efficient in solidity. You are not implementing binary search but something else, use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm as starting point. Don't copy the whole array it is too wasteful!!

Comment: It is never a good idea to perform sort operations `on chain`. Rather you can get the `sortArray` on front-end and sort and insert new value. Then send back the whole array to contract. This way you perform sort operations `off chain`.

Comment: I am starting to realize the iterative version would be the right way, in terms of simplicity and EVM load. Iftifar, in any other case, you would be right but when dealing with financial transactions, I cannot allow anyone to displace or inject any false values in to the array. That is why it must all be done contract side.

Comment: Your function doesn't return a value in all execution-paths. That by itself should ring an alarm bell.